# How to troubleshoot Aquamacs / Emacs - Problems opening files with TRAMP

Tags: mac, ssh, emacs, aquamacs, tramp

How to troubleshoot Aquamacs, or I guess standard Emacs troubleshooting techniques should work with Aquamacs too. In this case i'd want just to raise the logging level, but i'm interested in other possibilities as well as i'm just getting used to Aquamacs/Emacs.

The actual problem i'm having is that on occasion opening files via TRAMP (ie. ssh) Aquamacs just hangs. It seems to be able to get the file from the remote server and run it thru flymake (which doesn't work with tramp) but stops doing anything just before opening the file in a new tab. I don't get any error/debug/info messages. Aquamacs uses very little CPU after this. Only way to continue is Force Quit it and start over.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem opening files with Emacs/TRAMP from my MacBook.

You can turn on TRAMP debugging in your `~/.emacs` file:

```
(setq tramp-verbose 10)
```

After inserting that, restart Emacs and attempt to open your file again.  When TRAMP freezes up, try hitting `C-G` and then switch buffer (`C-x b`) to `*debug tramp/ssh REMOTEHOST*`.  Inspect that for possible problems.

In my case, Tramp was freezing with the status line:

```
Tramp: Inserting `ssh:REMOTEHOST:/path/to/FILE'...done
```

The Tramp debug log showed lines with:

```
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
```

I tracked this down to having turned on paging in my Mercurial setup, and `less` was warning that `TERM=dumb`.  This was easily fixed in my `~/.hgrc`:

```
[pager]
pager = LESS='FSRX' less -d
```

Finally, just for fun, here's the TRAMP setup in my `~/.emacs` file, which contains some small adjustments to make things run faster:

```
;; Tramp (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) for remote files
(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")
;; Backup (file~) disabled and auto-save (#file#) locally to prevent delays in editing remote files
(add-to-list 'backup-directory-alist
             (cons tramp-file-name-regexp nil))
(setq tramp-auto-save-directory temporary-file-directory)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ps` to look for the background tasks Emacs has started, in this case `ssh -e none REMOTEHOST` ... you could probably look for it in Activity Monitor as well I'm sure (and it should be flagged there as a child process of Aquamacs.app too).

```
vayo:~ chris$ ps a | grep ssh
14687 s002  Ss+    0:00.04 ssh -e none REMOTEHOST
14694 s003  R+     0:00.01 grep ssh
14653 s007  S+     0:00.15 ssh REMOTEHOST
```

Kill the task Aquamacs has started (with `-e none` in my case).

```
vayo:~ chris$ kill 14687
```

Continue using Aquamacs.

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar hang when using TRAMP. Usually, moving the mouse over the buffer and clicking somewhere within it will un-freeze TRAMP. Not sure why this happens, but you could give that a shot. If that doesn't work, I would just try passing a command through while it is hanging. Does it respond to commands?